# Websocket does not connect even in LAN after some failures

Tags: javascript, websocket

Here my `websocket.js` code:

```
let ws = null;
let connected = false;

const TIMER_RECONNECTION = 10000;
const TIMER_TIMEOUT = 8000;

setInterval(reconnect, TIMER_RECONNECTION);

const extractHostname = function (url) {
    let hostname;
    if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) hostname = url.split("/")[2];
    else hostname = url.split("/")[0];
    hostname = hostname.split(":")[0];
    hostname = hostname.split("?")[0];
    return hostname;
};

const composeWsAddress = function (address) {
    let scheme = "ws";
    if (document.location.protocol === "https:") scheme += "s";
    return scheme + "://" + address + ":8000/ws";
};

const open = function (address) {
    console.log("Connecting...");

    delete ws;
    ws = new WebSocket(address);
    ws.onopen = onOpen;
    ws.onclose = onClose;
    ws.onmessage = onMessage;

    setTimeout(() => {
        if (ws && ws.readyState === WebSocket.CONNECTING) {
            ws.close();
            connected = false;
            console.log("aborted!");
            return;
        }
    }, TIMER_TIMEOUT);
};

let onOpen = function() {
    console.log("success!");
    connected = true;
};

let onClose = function() {
    ws = null;
    connected = false;
};

let onMessage = function(event) {
};

WebSocketClient = {
    init: function() { }
};

function reconnect() {
    if (connected === false) {
        const address = composeWsAddress(extractHostname(location.href));
        open(address);
    }
}

$(function() {
    WebSocketClient.init();
    reconnect();
});
```

The expected behavior is:

1. try to connect to the websocket server
2. if the connection is not done within 8 seconds, abort it
3. every 10 seconds check the connection state: if not connected retry

It works quite well:

```
Connecting...
aborted!      [after 8 seconds]
Connecting... [after 2 more seconds]
aborted!      [after 8 seconds]
Connecting... [after 2 more seconds]
aborted!      [after 8 seconds]
success!
```

If it fails for a quite long time, not sure how much, say several minutes, then when the server it's available it continues to fail again for minutes before connecting.
Reloading the page does not help.

The only way I found to connect immediately (after this situation) is to close and open again the whole browser (Firefox).

But I cannot ask the user to do this!
How to improve my code to avoid such a behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simpler mechanism for reconnecting that uses the onError event:

```js
const open = function (address) {
    console.log("Connecting...");

    if(ws && ws.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED) ws.close();
    ws = new WebSocket(address);
    ws.onopen = onOpen;
    ws.onclose = onClose;
    ws.onmessage = onMessage;
    ws.onerror = onError;
};

let onError = function() {
    console.log("connection failed, reconnecting ...");
    setTimeout(reconnect, 1000);
};
```

I.e., no timed abortion and let the websocket do the timing. The onError event will tell you when it is time to do another reconnect try.

Whether this solves your problem needs some testing in your environment. Maybe the timed abortion and too early reconnect creates the problem.

Comment: Your code has several problems for me. Initially the connection fails very soon and almost every seconds it tries to reconnect. Then, it takes more and more time to fail. Finally, when the server is available it still takes a lot of time to connect (unless I restart the browser).

Comment: Furthermore, when it finally connects it creates as many clients as the failed trials!

Comment: I think in your open function you should check the readyState of the ws in order to avoid multiple websockets (instead of delete). I have added some code for this. Furthermore, you could increase the timeout to reconnect if you want longer time intervals after onerror.

Comment: With you last edit the multiple clients issue is fixed! But the behavior is still the same. By the way I DO NOT want longer time intervals! I'm looking for the opposite: whenever the server comes up it should connect immediately!

Comment: Did some test here: 1. ws server on, client connected. 2. ws server off, reconnecting starts. 3. after 300 reconnect attemps ws server started again. 4. immediate ws connection to server. 
The timeout until onerror event is fired is varying depending on other network traffic that is going on. Therefore, I think it is better to use the onerror event to do the reconnect timing.

Comment: Thanks for you report but here I don't have immediate connection after about 20+ failures. And I'm in LAN so no network traffic.